# How to redirect from one URL to another URL?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I redirect to another URL in a web page using JavaScript?

Comment: Not with HTML or JavaScript. You send an HTTP Location header with either a 301 or 302 status code. The specifics depend on your webserver and/or server side programming environment.

Answer (score 45):

```
window.location.href = "URL2"
```

inside a JS block on the page or in an included file; that's assuming you really want to do it on the client.  Usually, the server sends the redirect via a 300-series response.

Comment: With this code, when we going to webpage with `URL2` what happened? i want to redirect webpage `if user load webpage with URL1`

Answer (score 26):

Since you tagged the question with `javascript` and `html`...

For a purely HTML solution, you can use a `meta` tag in the `header` to "refresh" the page, specifying a different URL:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/somepage.html">
```

If you can/want to use JavaScript, you can set the `location.href` of the `window`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://www.yourdomain.com/somepage.html";
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can redirect anything or more URL via javascript, Just simple `window.location.href` with `if else`

Use this code,

```
<script>
if(window.location.href == 'old_url')
{
    window.location.href="new_url";
}


//Another url redirect
if(window.location.href == 'old_url2')
{
    window.location.href="new_url2";
}
</script>
```

You can redirect many URL's by this procedure. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect, just use `window.location`.  Like so:

```
window.location = "http://www.redirectedsite.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

Why javascript?

http://www.instant-web-site-tools.com/html-redirect.html

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.URL2.com"> 
</html>
```

Unless I'm missunderstanding...

Answer (score 1):

```
location.href = "Pagename.html";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use a meta tag to redirect to another url.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://webdesign.about.com/">`

http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm