# Doing a redirect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect from one URL to another URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824141/how-to-redirect-from-one-url-to-another-url)

I have the following jQuery function in which I am trying to re-direct to another page -- how would I do this?

```
$.post('/ajax/change_qc_status/',  {
        'qc_note': qc_note,
        'user': user
    }, 
    function(request){
        $.get('/summary/90') // this does nothing
    }
);
```

Note that if I go to the page `/summary/90` it is the correct page.

Comment: God how I hate `tab` spaces. You're *not* doing a redirect per se. You're trying to *asynchronously get* content. It's not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this at all.

Just use `window.location = "intended URL"`