# AngularJS: reload to a different location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know we can reload the current page in angularjs using  `$window.location.reload();`.

How can we reload to a different location, something like -

`$window.location.reload('/anotherUrl');`

Comment: it's not `angular` - it's `javascript`, which `angular` is using.
your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824141/how-to-redirect-from-one-url-to-another-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **use AngularJS** to change the view from code and add the change to history do this:

```
$location.url('/anotherUrl');
```

(if you want to lose current page's search (query params) and hash),

or

```
$location.path('/anotherurl');
```

(if you want to pass current url's search (query params) and hash to the new page)

If you don't want to add this change to history do this:

```
$location.replace();
$location.url('/anotherUrl');
```

or

```
$location.replace();
$location.path('/anotherurl');
```

`$location.replace();` will maintain your state without re-instantiating your scope or controller.  If you truly **do** want to reload the page (and thereby lose your state) you could fall back to the pure JavaScript solution given in the comment made by @null, that you have requested be given as an answer, or use the method I outline above and then call:

```
$route.reload();
```

Please see [this link for replace(); documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#replace).

I have assumed you are using routing since your question is asking how to do this using AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to redirect to different location, for that you can use window services like this

```
$window.location.href = 'anotherUrl' ;
```

Comment: or `location.replace('/anotherUrl')` if you wanna replace the history entry.

Comment: @null you are right, plz make it an answer so i can close this post.

Comment: `$window.location.href = 'anotherUrl'` will have the same result as `location.replace('/anotherUrl')` => no reloading

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is to use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service.

Specifically, you can set a new url with this:

```
$location.path('/anotherUrl');
```

Comment: `$location.path('/anotherUrl')` will not reload the page :(